# Trying to Install MySQL with/for Ruby on Ubuntu, keep getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, and I installed Ruby and Rails via rbenv as reccomended by others and the Ruby docs. I am trying to setup a MySQL server to use with an application and I first need to gem install it. Even when signed in as root, I keep getting the following error when issuing the command

```
gem install mysql2
```

error shown

[image: 1]

I've tried un-installing and re-installing Ruby, and I've tried changing the permissions of the gems folder. Permission changes don't seem to be permanent

Comment: The system version of ruby is probably being used.

Try to compare
ruby -v
and
rbenv version

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: I am not expert with Linux yet you should not install Ruby as root, then you probably have to create your Rails app as root too and your app inherits super user rights which is a problem in case your app is hacked. And also produce this kind of rights mismatches.  You probably have installed Ruby as root and trying to start the server as `rails server` but then your Rails server cannot have access to the Ruby files. Also you need to install Mysql on ubuntu but this can be done with `sudo` as you can probably (like Postgres)  create some Mysql users with certain rights .

Comment: I recomment deleting your app (moving the app folder to bin), reinstalling Ruby with your current user, installing Mysql as sudo and creating a mysql user with all the needed rights : creating databases, deleting databases etc ...